# How can I define what make start activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent

my app is like cycle .  first a activity starts. then b . this goes on like c,d and again a.   How can I know that a is run by what ? is a normal app starting or have made an intent it run ?

Answer (score 1):

you could add some extra to the intent when activity "d" is starting activity "a", and check for this extra.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getCallingActivity() on the activity to get the name of the activity that invoked this activity.

Comment: this occurs error. because I must use there getIntent.getExtra()... first because of not being an intent , checking this occurs error

Comment: For using getExtra() I suggest to add an extra in activity "d" as bigstones suggested.